# Why do we have the output : S1S2 in this case?

Tags: java

In the code below, the output is : S1S2. Why do we get the that result?

```
 public class S1 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new S2();
     }
     S1(){
         System.out.print("S1");
     }
 }
 class S2 extends S1{
     S2(){
         System.out.print("S2");
     }
 }
```

Comment: look up [constructor chaining](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor.html).

Comment: +1 for a good question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since S2 extends S1, it's equivalent to calling all the constructors in a top-level down order.

Java will first create the parent object, S1 and call it's constructor. Then move down to the next object, S2 with it's constructor.

Comment: Well it will first call `Object's` constructor from `S1`.

Answer (score 2):

If a derived class's constructor doesn't explicitly call its base class's constructor (via `super(...)`) then there is an implicit call

```
super();
```

to the base class's default constructor in each derived class's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor of a subclass, there is an implicit call to the superclass's default constructor.

Here is a quote from the Spec :

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor
>   invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the
>   primordial class Object, then the constructor body is implicitly
>   assumed by the compiler to begin with a superclass constructor
>   invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct
>   superclass that takes no arguments.